# jQuery height() problem

Tags: jquery

How do we go about accessing a height for a Gridview? The Gridview has a CSS attribute called height that is set to 800px, but I haven't been able to access anything with height()

$('ctl00_MainContent_grdPersonResults').height() = null

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking an .Net GridView or is this a specific jQ plugin or are you using the term generically. Can you elaborate (and if .Net specific the add particular tags to the question)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to get an element by id you need to prepend a pound sign/hash to use the id selector.

```
$('#ctl00_MainContent_grdPersonResults').height()...
```

without it, it will be selecting based on elements having the string as a class name.  I'm sure that none of your controls would have that as a class name so the selector is failing.  Note that because of the ASP.NET mangles names, though, it may be easier to assign a class name and use the class name selector.

Comment: +1: I can't remember how many times I've done this same thing.

Comment: +1 arr, I also forgot that when pasting @jlrolin's code. Good catch

Comment: +1 Ive done it as well... more than id like to admit - in fact i didnt even catch it in his question.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('ctl00_MainContent_grdPersonResults').innerHeight();
```

innHeight(): http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/innerHeight